# WPF value converter making 1000s of database trips when it could be done in one

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a list view that is bound to an Items collection in the view model behind. This works quite well, in that it shows the data correctly and groups it properly.

```
   <!--  The list view for the shoeprint images  -->
   <ListView Grid.Row="0"
             Margin="3,-3,-3,3"
             Background="Transparent"
             BorderThickness="0"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Items"}
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             SelectionMode="Single">
    </ListView

        /// <summary>
        /// The collection that handles the grouping for the list view
        /// </summary>
        public ICollectionView Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
            private set
            {
                _items = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Items"));
            }
        }

private void UpdateDisplay()
{
            var lst = new CollectionViewSource { Source = new ObservableCollection<ShoeprintImage>(concatList) };
            lst.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Type"));
          /*OK UNTIL THIS LINE*/  Items = lst.View;
}
```

Up until the third line in Update display there are minimal database calls to generate the items collection and it is all quite speedy and efficient.

However each list view item consists of an image and a text block which holds a text string depending on certain properties of the item.

When I bind to the text block I use a value converter that takes the item, and checks these properties to see what string it should display.

The problem is that for every item it makes a round trip to the database to get its information. I would like to have it preload this information for every item before the converter as I believe it could be done in one SQL statement instead of 1000s of round trips.

could someone give me an idea of how to proceed? if you need more information I will post it but trying to keep it as short as possible as I hate reading long essay questions :-)

**EDIT - Converter code**

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    //do nothing if value is null
    if (value == null) return Binding.DoNothing;

    //get the value 
    var image = (ShoeprintImage)value;

    bool isPartofGroup = true;

    //we only want the word Group to appear on the search results
    if (image.Type == Enumerations.ImageType.GroupMembers || image.Type == Enumerations.ImageType.Shortlist) isPartofGroup = false;
    else
    {
        var group = image.Item.ItemGroups.First().Group;
        if (group.GroupID == 0) isPartofGroup = false;
        else
        {
            if (group.ItemGroups.Count() <= 1) isPartofGroup = false;
        }
    }

    //get the string
    if (isPartofGroup) return Strings.GroupString;
    else return string.Empty;
}
```

**EDIT - binding (this is in the list view item template**

```
   <!--  put a stack panel so the image is above the text  -->
                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Background="White">

                                <!--  The image to display  -->
                                <Image x:Name="MainImage"
                                       Width="75"
                                       Height="125"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                       MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                                       MouseRightButtonDown="Image_MouseRightButtonDown"
                                       Source="{Binding ImageFromFile}" />

                                <!--  Displays the word "Group" if the image is part of a group  -->
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           FontStyle="Italic"
                                           FontWeight="Bold"
                                           Foreground="ForestGreen"
                                           Padding="2"
                                           Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource GroupConverter},
                                                          Mode=OneWay}"
                                           TextAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Just disable entity framework lazy loading

Comment: done - @ChrisEelmaa difficult to do as I make extensive use of Lazy loading elsewhere in the app

Comment: Aside from the obvious (Include extension method) you could try loading the images from the database, first, if it's a many to one relationship. Then EF will have the images cached in its identity map.